# map [] operator segfault

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, segmentation-fault

When you add something to a stl map, what are the circumstances under which acess [] operator may lead to segfault??

how to validate it.
Example:
There is a class TimerManager that maintains a map of ids to events.

```
map<int, long> _timerIdsMap; 

Struct GUI
{
   TimerManager manager;
}
```

I then register myself and it works perfectly fine.

When I issue the call to stop timer, that is when , there is a crash observed sometimes.

```
bool TimerManager::stop_timer( int specifiedEvent )
{
    TRACE("TimerManager::stop_timer() Enter");
    bool retVal = true;
    long timerId = _timerIdsMap[specifiedEvent];

(gdb) where
#0  0x00002adb5d9585a0 in std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, long>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, long> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, long> > >::_M_begin() () from Utils.so
#1  0x00002adb5d95954c in std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, long>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, long> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, long> > >::lower_bound(int const&) () from Utils.so
#2  0x00002adb5d959583 in std::map<int, long, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, long> > >::lower_bound(int const&) ()
   from Utils.so
#3  0x00002adb5d95d6fa in std::map<int, long, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, long> > >::operator[](int const&) ()
   from Utils.so
#4  0x00002adb5d95657f in TimerManager::stop_timer(int) ()
```

The question that i have is how do i validate if `map[]` contains a valid member or not.

This is the way I call the `stopTimer` function:

```
const int TIMERID = 5;

void completeTest(GtkWidget* myWidget,GdkEvent  *event,gpointer   data)
{
    cout<<" test is completed"<<endl;

    GUI* _ptrGUI = (GUI *)data;

    if(_ptrGUI!=NULL)
    {       
        cout<<"stop timer"<<endl;

        if(!_ptrGUI->_timerManager.stop_timer(TIMERID))
        {
            cout<<"fatal error, could not stop the timer"<<endl;
        }
```

Comment: Can you please expand on the code causing the problem, like how do you call the `stop_timer` function? And in the debugger, can you please print the value of `this`?

Comment: I have expanded the cod enow to include the code where i call it...Is there anyway i can confirm if the map contains a valid data at that particular location....I just dont want it to segfault

Comment: does a struct instead of a class make a difference here??

Comment: The most likely culprit is that the `GUI` object has already been destroyed at that point, or that it has never been properly initialised.

Comment: @basav not at all, but where does that uppercase **S** come from ?

Comment: Struct is a typo....It's struct

Answer (score 0):

This means there is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) somewhere in your code. Possible reasons are many, and could include:

- The `TimerManager` object and/or `_timerIdsMap` have already been destroyed.
- There is a memory corruption somewhere (for example, a buffer overrun).
- etc

A good starting point might be to [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) your code.

Comment: that is a valid point..I will do a valgrind but is there anyway to check if the map contains a valid data at that particular location....i donot want it to segfault

Comment: @basav: If you have undefined behaviour, all bets are off and there is no way to check for that. The only reliable way to fix this is by fixing the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a segfault here because:

1. You are accessing non-existing element in map - it is better to use find method in such case
2. You are not catching exceptions that thread - better to catch exception and if you need to exit to do it gracefully

Comment: Nope, `operator[]` default-consctructs the element if it doesn't exist. `at()` is the function that throws instead.

Comment: yes, operator[] default-constructs the element, so if key doesn't exist OP getting wrong value and doesn't know about it. that if why it is better to use find here.

Comment: The program crashed deep into the implementation of `std::map::operator[]`, so this probably isn't the bug (yet).